# C# regex to match words containing known substrings and not equal to specific keywords

Tags: c#, regex

I need to verify if a string contains "error" or "exception" in it, excluding certain keywords: "exception1", "exception2", "includeException", "error1".

This regex seems to do the job:

```
\b\w*(?!exception1)(?!exception2)(?!includeException)(?!error1)(exception|error)\w*\b
```

It correctly returns 2 matches when run against the following string:

```
Test string: "exception1 exception2 exception3 includeException error1 error2"
Matches: "exception3", "error2"
```

However, if I set the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag or add "`(?i)`" at the beginning of the Regex it also returns a match for "`includeException`".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two main bottlenecks with your regex:

- It has several unanchored lookaheads (when unanchored, they usually do not help unless used in a tempered greedy token and other complex patterns)
- The `\w*` subpatterns are placed on both sides of lookaheads, thus, removing any impact from the lookaheads.

The problem with case-insensitivity is described in Berin's answer, you want to match the word `exception` and `includeException` contains that substring. So, a possible solution is *to add a leading word boundary* to `(error|exception)` pattern:

```
\b\w*(?!exception1)(?!exception2)(?!includeException)(?!error1)\b(exception|error)\w*\b
                                                               ^^
```

However, **if you need to match words containing `error` or `exception`**, **that ARE NOT EQUAL to specific keywords**, use

```
\b(?!(?:exception1|exception2|includeException|error1)\b)\w*(exception|error)\w*\b
```

Here, the lookaheads are anchored to the leading word boundary, they are only checked *once* after each word boundary, not at each position inside a word. Certainly, you can contract it further: `\b(?!(?:exception[12]|includeException|error1)\b)\w*(exception|error)\w*\b`.

Now, **if you need to match words containing `error` or `exception`**, **that DO NOT CONTAIN specific keywords**, use

```
\b(?!\w*(?:exception1|exception2|includeException|error1))\w*(exception|error)\w*\b
```

***All regex patterns used here are tested at [regexhero.net](http://regexhero.net/tester/)***

Comment: Please let me know which of the regexps works for you best, I will add more explanations.

Comment: The regex's here definitely work.  I found another regex tester that does a good job of explaining the results: https://myregextester.com/index.php  I think it was a little more helpful than what I used for my initial answer.

Comment: Thx guys! I ended up using this regex (mentioned above), as I actually needed to match words that were not equal to specific keywords: \b(?!(?:exception1|exception2|includeException|error1)\b)\w*(exception|error)\w*\b

Answer (score 3):

Using a good Regex tester can help you figure out what's actually being matched.  I used this one:

http://regexhero.net/tester/

In the results where it highlights the matches, there is a small button with an 'i' for information.  So the reason that it's matching `innerException` when it's case insensitive is because you are matching the latter half of the word.  The regex doesn't require white space separating the words.

Your regex would match with case invariant off if `innerException` were written as `innerexception` because your positive match `(exception|error)` is matching the last half.  You can also see that when you start removing spaces.  `exception1exception2` doesn't match, but `exception1exception2exception3` does.

While Regex is very compact, there are several ways to get it wrong.  A straightforward approach might be a better solution in this case.

Changing your regex to remove the last wildcard `*` characters will make what you have work the way you want:

```
\b\w*(?!exception1)(?!exception2)(?!includeException)(?!error1)(exception|error)\w\b
```

Comment: Thx Berin. Removing the last wildcard results in words like "error" not getting matched though.

Comment: My main contribution was introducing the regex testers.  Check out @stribizhev answer for a better regex.

Answer (score 2):

Regex is not very readable... how about a pure C# solution?

```
public static Boolean ContainsErrorOrExceptionExcept(this string input, string[] excludedKeywords)
{
    if (input.Contains("error") || input.Contains("exception"))
    {
        foreach (string x in excludedKeywords)
        {
            if (input.Contains(x))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }       
}
```